# How to return String form actionPerformed?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to use buttons to control actions performed on a window. To do this I'm trying to return strings to give commands across the program. So far I managed to get this code to work:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    setCommand(e.getActionCommand());
}

public void setCommand(String g){
    command = g;
    getCommand();
}

public String getCommand() {
    return command;
}
```

However when I do this in a different class nothing happens:

```
System.out.print(button.getCommand());
```

Am I doing something wrong or am I simply using the wrong solution?

Comment: Your `setCommand` implementation looks all wrong. Apart from the nonsense call to the getter, the String argument is getting ignored. You didn't give enough code for me to really see where your approach is headed.

Comment: Marko, why so? The code gives me the result I need all the way to the getCommand method. The problem is using its result where I need it.

Comment: And what do you intend to achieve with the `getCommand()` call in `setCommand`? It is a no-operation call. The return value will be ignored.

Comment: All the getCommand needs to do is return the String, after it was set by the setCommand. I couldn't possibly call the setCommand from another class because it takes a parameter that is set later by the actionPerformed method. I'm not very experienced in Java so I'm trying to understand how this works. This feels to me very much like a workaround, if there is a batter way please tell me.

Comment: As the answerers below have pointed out, `void` methods have no return value, and anyway, the only way to return a value is with a `return` statement. If you are literally trying to make `actionPerformed` return a value, stop trying. You need an inversion-of-control principle where your `actionPerformed` method **pushes** the string somewhere, instead of expecting the caller of that method to **pull** the string. The caller is not under your control anyway, it's the main run loop of the GUI.

Comment: I thought that you already had the idea of pushing the value since you are setting the string to an instance variable.

Comment: If you want the buttons to issue commands, then make `actionPerformed` initiate those commands itself. That's inversion of control: you have the string there, **use it**.

Comment: Thanks Marko. So let me understand. I'd have actionPerformed call the methods that perform the actions I want to perform?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see the `actionPerformed()` has a `void` return type... and its method that you are **overridding from the** `ActionListener` Interface... so you **cannot return a String** from it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return something from the `actionPerfomed()` method, but you can instead call other methods that would do whatever you need them to do when that button is pressed.

If you want to notify other business logic that a certain button was pressed, then I would suggest you use the Observer pattern.